# Need to show agreement according to language selected in a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, development, office-365, codeplex

I added html form webpart to show the languages like a dropdown and added content editor webpart to add the text. I created each language in a 'div' and trying to pull the text by id given for dropdown.

```
    <select id="lang" name="lang">
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">Chinese</option>
    <option value="3">Czech</option>
    <option value="4">German</option>
    <option value="5">Hungarian</option>
    <option value="6">Italian</option>
    <option value="7">Japanese</option>
    <option value="8">Slovak</option>
    <option value="9">Spanish</option>
    </select>
```

and the code i wrote not working can you let me know any changes in this code.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

     /* By default all lang will be hidden*/
     $("#2").hide();
     $("#3").hide();
     $("#4").hide();
      $("#5").hide();
     $("#6").hide();
     $("#7").hide();
     $("#8").hide();
     $("#9").hide();
     $("#10").hide();

     });

     $(function() {
     $("select[name='WPQ4lang']").change(function() {

  var langDrpDown= $("select[name='WPQ4lang']").val();
  if(langDrpDown== '1'){

  $("#1").show();
  $("#2").hide();
  $("#3").hide();
  $("#4").hide();
  $("#5").hide();
  $("#6").hide();
  $("#7").hide();
  $("#8").hide();
  $("#9").hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the correct Name of your select control at the following lines

```
$("select[name='lang']").change(function() {

  var langDrpDown= $("select[name='lang']").val();
```

Or try the following code that tested in script editor on my side and match your requirements:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#lang').change(function(){
                     $("#lang option:selected").text();
                        if( $(this).attr('value') =='2')
                            {
                                 $("#Qassas").show();
                                 $("#Qassas1").hide();
                            }
                        else
                            {
                                 $("#Qassas").hide();
                                 $("#Qassas1").hide();
                            }
                   });
                });
    </script>

    <select id="lang" name="lang">
    <option value="1">English</option>
    <option value="2">Chinese</option>
    <option value="3">Czech</option>
    <option value="4">German</option>
    <option value="5">Hungarian</option>
    <option value="6">Italian</option>
    <option value="7">Japanese</option>
    <option value="8">Slovak</option>
    <option value="9">Spanish</option>
    </select>

    <div id="Qassas">qassas</div>
    <div id="Qassas1">qassas1</div>
```